# Confusion between Passing by Value or Reference

Tags: c, parameter-passing

The question I am attempting to complete in prep for an exam is as follows:

: Consider a function with this prototype:
void convert( char list[], char ch 1, char ch2);
The "convert" function changes each character chi that it finds inside "list" into
character ch2. For example, the function call "convert (name,'a','z')" would convert each
'a' to a 'z' inside an array called "name". Write the definition of function "convert".

My program runs up to the end of the two scanf functions in main, I am looking how to pass the parameters without using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char list[];
char ch1;
char ch2;

void convert(char list[], char ch1, char ch2);

int main()
{
    char list[15];
    char ch1, ch2;
    printf("Enter a string of characters:");
    scanf("%s", list);
    printf("Enter the first letter:");
    scanf("%c\n", &ch1);
    printf("Enter the second letter:");
    scanf("%c\n", &ch2);
}
void convert(char list[], char ch1, char ch2)
{
    int wordcount;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    if (list[i] == ch1)
    {
        x++;
        list[i] = ch2;

    }
    else if (list[i] != ch1)
    {
        y++;


    }
    else if (list[i] == NULL)
    {
        wordcount = (y + x + 1);

    } 

    printf("In the string there are %d letters and in %s the letter %c was changed to %c, %d          times.", wordcount , list, ch1, ch2, x);
```

}

Comment: call `convert(list, ch1, ch2);` at main. but 1st argument of convert (`char list[]`) is **pointer**, not array.

Comment: when Array pass to function, pass by value( of pointer). if you can change prototype, wrap of Array by struct pass by value (include array).

Comment: Thanks, I thought the idea behind declaring Global variables was to enable various function to work with the variable. Also I just wanted clarify that the pointer goes at the beginning of main where the string is written in?

Comment: In this case pointer that was passed to the function points to the string of main.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Congratulations on 20,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ch1 and ch2 are already global, so you don't need to pass anything to convert. Like this:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 
  4 char list[15];
  5 char ch1;
  6 char ch2;
  7 
  8 void convert();
  9 
 10 int main()
 11 {
 12     scanf("%c\n",&ch1);
 13     scanf("%c",&ch2);
 14     printf("char 1: %c, char2: %c\n",ch1,ch2);
 15     convert();
 16     printf("char 1: %c, char2: %c\n",ch1,ch2);
 17     return 0;
 18 }
 19 
 20 void convert()
 21 {
 22     char temp;
 23     temp=ch1;
 24     ch1=ch2;
 25     ch2=temp;
 26 }
```

Comment: no problem, if this answer works for you, you should mark it as the accepted answer (the check mark, click to turn it green)

Answer (score 3):

To be strict there is no "passing by reference" in C like in Fortran or with `var` in Pascal. All arguments are passed just "by value" (sometimes it's called "by copy" as well).

The first parameter declaration in:

```
void convert(char list[], char ch1, char ch2) { .. }
```

means effectively:

```
void convert(char *list, char ch1, char ch2) { .. }
```

where `list` is function's local pointer variable of type `char *`. It has nothing common with `list` array declared in `main()`. In other words both are located in different scope. What we say is that array `list` (from `main()`) "decays" to pointer, that holds address of its first element, then such pointer's value is assigned into `list` parameter.